# Why doesn't my C# calculator app work?

Tags: c#, winforms, calculator

So for some reason, it's adding the numbers fine, except for when i try to add with decimals... for example... if i type 2 + 2 it gives me 4, which is right, BUT if i type 
2 + 1.2, instead of showing 3.2 on the textbox, it shows 14, so it's taking 1.2 as a 12... it's not counting the "." dot... the code is very long so I did a sample one with the same issue...

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    double num1, num2, answer;
    string add, Op;
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + ("1");
    }

    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + ("2");
    }

    private void button5_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + (".");
    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num1 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        textBox1.Text = "";
        Op = "add";
    }

    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        num2 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox1.Text);
        switch (Op)
        { 
            case "add":
        answer = num1 + num2;
        textBox1.Text = Convert.ToString(answer);
        break; 
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Maybe you can find useful my demostration project: https://github.com/theraot/SimpleCalculator

Comment: I don't see anything wrong with this code, and how I *think* you're using it. Can you expand on the steps you take to use your program? Is `textBox1` the only text box on your form (are you sure)?

Comment: Obviously based on the description there is a bug in the code somewhere but the segment provided is not sufficient to determine what that bug is! (MORE CODE!!)

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta yeah it is the only textBox i'm using and i mean after declaring the variables i did this for every number and for the "." as well:  

private void button10_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + ("0");
        }

        private void button11_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text + (".");
        }
 I just don't know why it isnt taking the "." dot when doing the math and displaying the answer

Comment: drew has a point, that I was avoiding bringing up because minimal WinForms apps can be large. But: can you create and post a [Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example](http://sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem? Keep it short, but make sure it's got the same issue.

Comment: ...in addition, when I asked for the steps you take, I mean how you use the program (*enter "10" in the textbox, press "Button15", enter "1.5" in the textbox, press "Button18", observe "25" in the textbox.*)

Comment: What is that button10 and button11 code supposed to be doing? We really need that SSCCE.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta there I eddited the code so u can check it out and see if you can figure out what's wrong with it, thank's a lot i really appreciate ur help

Comment: Please see my comment two up. I need to see the steps you take, when you use your program. Be specific and detailed.

Comment: For example, I grabbed your code and ran it. It worked, adding the numbers correctly, when I used this procedure: *Enter "2" in the textbox. Press button4. Enter "1.2" in the textbox. Press button3. Observe "3.2" in the textbox.*

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta the button 10 and 11 were just examples of what I did with every button number, I edited the post and placed the code of a small version of what I'm working on that seems to show the same issue... for example, in the code I just reposted up there where the question is, this is what's going on: If enter "1" in the textbox, then i press "button 4" and enter "1.2" and press "button 3", it shows "13" in the textbox as an answer, instead of a "2.2"

Comment: You used the word "repuesta" before. Are you Spanish, or working on a system with Spanish regional settings? I see that the Spanish decimal separator is ",", not "." (comma, not period), which could cause this problem (it will cause *some* kind of problem). Fredou's on to something. Check your region settings, the decimal symbol.

Comment: @MichaelPetrotta I just checked and you're right, yeah I'm spanish but I had no idea you had to use a comma when it comes to spanish... I wasted a good two hours trying to figure it out, thanks a lot anyways and sorry for the inconvinience! have a good day!

Comment: You're welcome. Fredou really answered your question, below; I just added a bit, and made sure you were aware of it. If you thought his answer was helpful, you should "accept" it, by clicking the hollow green arrow.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

so I created this;

```
using System;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var num1 = Convert.ToDouble("2");
        var num2 = Convert.ToDouble("1.2");
        var answer = num1 + num2;
        Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToString(answer));
        Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
}
```

it does work.

now if you change

```
 var num2 = Convert.ToDouble("1.2");
```

to

```
 var num2 = Convert.ToDouble("1,2");
```

a comma, it will show the same result as you

can you check your localization setting and make sure "." (dot) is the decimal symbol/point for your computer? (control panel) or if you prefer run this and click on "additional setting..." button

```
  C:\Windows\System32\rundll32.exe shell32.dll,Control_RunDLL intl.cpl,,0
```

Comment: Nice guess! Seems likely to be the issue.

Comment: thanks a lot man! yup! that was the issue actually.